# Android MuPDF - disable paging

Tags: android, pdf, mupdf

Im using MuPDF library, and i want to disable auto scrolling to next \ previous page when user between 2 pages. any idea?

Comment: Please explain clearly.

Comment: I use Ubuntu and mupdf and with specifically one pdf file, it scrolls/turns automatic to the next page by magic hand. How to avoid that?